# Find the n most common values in a vector

Tags: r, count, ranking

I have a vector say

```
c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,7,5,7,7,7)
```

How do I count each element, and then return the e.g. 3 most common elements, i.e. 1, 7, 5?

Comment: you can use table().. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but the answer is simple:

```
sort(table(variable),decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]
```

Comment: use `table(variable, useNA = "ifany")` if you're checking if `NA` is the most frequent value. otherwise `NA`s will get dropped!

Comment: @DavidT: that is not correct

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this is better than the table approach, but if your list is already a factor then its summary method will give you frequency counts:

```
> summary(as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,7,5,7,7,7)))
1 2 3 4 5 7 
6 1 1 1 2 5
```

And then you can get the top 3 most frequent like so:

```
> names(sort(summary(as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,7,5,7,7,7))), decreasing=T)[1:3])
[1] "1" "7" "5"
```

Answer (score 9):

If your vector contains only integers, `tabulate` will be *much* faster than anything else. There are a couple of catches to be aware of:

- It'll by default return the count for numbers from 1 to N.
- It'll return an unnamed vector.

That means, if your `x = c(1,1,1,3)` then `tabulate(x)` will return `(3, 0, 1)`. Note that the counts are for `1 to max(x)` by default.

How can you use `tabulate` to make sure that you can pass any numbers?

```
set.seed(45)
x <- sample(-5:5, 25, TRUE)
#  [1]  1 -2 -3 -1 -2 -2 -3  1 -3 -5 -1  4 -2  0 -1 -1  5 -4 -1 -3 -4 -2  1  2  4
```

Just add `abs(min(x))+1` when `min(x) <= 0` to make sure that the values start from 1. If `min(x) > 0`, then just use `tabulate` directly.

```
sort(setNames(tabulate(x + ifelse(min(x) <= 0, abs(min(x))+1, 0)), 
      seq(min(x), max(x))), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]
```

---

If your vector does contain `NA`, then you can use `table` with `useNA="always"` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

you can use table() function to get a tabulation of the frequency of values in an array/vector and then sort this table.

```
x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
sort(table(x))
2 1
2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gathered a few answers to this question over different threads, and run a `microbenchmark` comparison (on a Windows-based computing server running R 4.3.0 with 512 Gb RAM and 2 AMD processors with 24 cores).

I compare 4 methods, based on dplyr, data.table, base R, and Rfast:

```
library(dplyr)

# dplyr based function
mostfreqval1 <- function(x,k=1){
  tibble(v=x) %>% count(v) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% slice(1:k) %>% pull(v)
}

# using data.table 
mostfreqval2 <- function(x,k=1){
  require(data.table)
  ds <- data.table(x)
  setkey(ds,x)
  sorted <- ds[,.N,by=list(x)]
  return(sorted[order(-N)]$x[1:k])
}

# using Base R
mostfreqval3 <- function(x,k=1){
  x %>% table() %>% sort(decreasing=TRUE) %>% names() %>% head(k) 
}

# Base R boosted by Rfast
mostfreqval4 <- function(x,k=1){
  x %>% Rfast::Table() %>% sort(decreasing=TRUE) %>% names() %>% head(k)
}

set.seed(123)
myvec <- sample(letters[1:10], 1e6, replace=TRUE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval1(k=3))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval2(k=3))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval3(k=3))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval4(k=3))
```

All functions return the same output: a vector `c("d","j","a")`.

In terms of speed, the results are the following:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval1(k=3))
Unit: milliseconds
                          expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 myvec %>% mostfreqval1(k = 3) 22.2394 23.5893 24.00849 24.08615 24.4052 25.6265   100
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval2(k=3))
Unit: milliseconds
                          expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 myvec %>% mostfreqval2(k = 3) 23.7754 24.44535 24.84656 24.7828 25.1395 26.6308   100
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval3(k=3))
Unit: milliseconds
                          expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq     max
 myvec %>% mostfreqval3(k = 3) 41.9721 42.3926 43.45681 42.62645 43.23245 49.9802
 neval
   100
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myvec %>% mostfreqval4(k=3))
Unit: milliseconds
                          expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 myvec %>% mostfreqval4(k = 3) 19.0955 19.12415 19.19986 19.1526 19.2288 19.9925   100
```

With these specifications, the *dplyr*-based, *data.table*-based and *Rfast*-based solutions are about equivalent in terms of speed. The Base R solution is the slowest one. I have noticed that dplyr and data.table are better for smaller problems (e.g., when the vector size is lower than 1e5) but Rfast catches up for larger vector sizes.

Note that the ranking is similar when the comparison is run on a MacBook Pro, except that the data.table solution becomes significantly slower, probably due the lack of support of OpenMP on MacOS).

Happy to add any other function to this comparison, in case you find it useful.