# apply a function to each element of a column individually

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Let us assume following as my data table `data`

```
data <- setDT(structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), col2 = c(53, 45, 54, 
97, 23), col3 = c("aa aa aa aa ab ad af ae ar", "bb bb bb bb bt by bu bi bo", 
"cc cc cc cc cd cy ch cn cd", "dd dd dd dd dt dy dj dk da", "ee ee ee ee et eh es er eg"
), col4 = c("aa bb ff ff","aa ff vv rr","dd dd rr gg",
"yy yy rr rr","uu uu uu ee")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))

col1     col2    col3                            col4
1        53      aa aa aa aa ab ad af ae ar      aa bb ff ff
2        45      bb bb bb bb bt by bu bi bo      aa ff vv rr
3        54      cc cc cc cc cd cy ch cn cd      dd dd rr gg
4        97      dd dd dd dd dt dy dj dk da      yy yy rr rr
5        23      ee ee ee ee et eh es er eg      uu uu uu ee
```

`col3` has strings of words and I need to find that if the most frequently occurred `word` in col3 appears in `col4` or not. So output will look like as follows:

```
col1     col2    col3                            col4          most_freq_word_in_cool3       out_col
1        53      aa aa aa aa ab ad af ae ar      aa bb ff ff             aa                      1  
2        45      bb bb bb bb bt by bu bi bo      aa ff vv rr             bb                      0
3        54      cc cc cc cc cd cy ch cn cd      dd dd rr gg             cc                      0  
4        97      dd dd dd dd dt dy dj dk da      yy yy rr rr             dd                      0 
5        23      ee ee ee ee et eh es er eg      uu uu uu ee             ee                       1
```

I tried the following solution

```
    m_fre_word1 <- function(x) { string <- as.character(unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
                                freq <- sort(table(string), decreasing = T)
                                wr <-names(freq)[1]
                                return(wr) }

    data <- data[ , most_freq_word_in_cool3:= apply(data[ , .(col3)], 1, m_fre_word1)]
    data <- data[ , out_col:= as.numeric(grepl(m_fre_word1(col3), col4))]
```

There is nothing wrong with this solution, but it is really slow. My data table is huge. I can't use this way so I am looking for a faster alternative. Could somebody suggest a faster alternative.

Thanks,

Comment: To make this easily reproducible, post the `dput` of the data frame.

Comment: @PierreLafortune How do i do it?

Comment: `dput(data)` It will look like `structure(....(data.table))`

Comment: There is no need in `data <- data` btw.

Comment: @PierreLafortune done!

Comment: Here's a suggestion: finding your most common element is currently done by sorting (in decreasing order) and getting the first element. This has time complexity of O(n log n). You can do it in O(n) time and space.

Comment: @YuppieNetworking but strings of `col3` are not that big. Do you think sorting is the most time consuming part?

Comment: @user3664020 Ah, I thought that your real data had much more elements in `col3`. For lower n values, this is not going to be the bottleneck

Comment: Would be helpful to include col4 in your dput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt. Instead of running this whole thing on each row, I would suggest to split the column and operate on a long format.

I'm stealing the `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode) and it is defined as follows

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Now using the newest `data.table` version we could do

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.6+
temp <- setDT(data6)[, tstrsplit(col3, " ", fixed = TRUE)]
data6[, res := melt(temp[, indx := .I], id = "indx")[, Mode(value), by = indx]$V1]
data6

#    col1 col2                       col3        col4 res
# 1:    1   53 aa aa aa aa ab ad af ae ar aa bb ff ff  aa
# 2:    2   45 bb bb bb bb bt by bu bi bo aa ff vv rr  bb
# 3:    3   54 cc cc cc cc cd cy ch cn cd dd dd rr gg  cc
# 4:    4   97 dd dd dd dd dt dy dj dk da yy yy rr rr  dd
# 5:    5   23 ee ee ee ee et eh es er eg uu uu uu ee  ee
```

---

The second step can be easily achieved by eitehr

```
data6[, out := +grepl(res, col4, fixed = TRUE), by = res]
```

**OR** (not sure which one is faster)

```
library(stringi)
data6[stri_detect_fixed(col4, res), out := 1L]
```

---

As a side note, when using reference semantics, there is no need to copy the whole data set and reassign it using `<-`, in fact that's the whole point of reference semantics. Please read [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

Comment: Presumably the stringi gives you NAs instead of zeros. Could add a `[, out:=0L]` before it.

Comment: @Frank I know, I figured that it's not that important, because it is both easy to fix or OP can just filter by `!is.na(out)` or `sum(out, na.rm = TRUE)` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `apply(data[ , .(col3)]` is what is slowing down your code. Generally I have found putting a subset within a data.table call causes huge slowdowns, as the subset operation is expensive.

You can try:

```
DT[ , test := names(sort(table(strsplit(col3," ")), decreasing = T))[1], by = col1]
DT[, search := gsub(" ","|",col4)]
DT[, output := grepl(search,test), by = col1]
```

Not sure if my or David's answer will be faster.

EDIT: Based on Frank's input , the last two lines can be replaced with:

```
DT[, output := mapply(grepl,gsub(" ","|",col4),test)]
```

Comment: Speed might be improved by skipping the `by` (and creation of a `search` col): `DT[, output := mapply(grepl,gsub(" ","|",col4),test)]`. Also, I guess `tabulate` is faster than `table`, if you can figure how to switch.

Comment: Ran microbenchmark and you are right. Getting to one line is the biggest improvement, and then replacing by with mapply adds a tiny bit. Edited to reflect

Comment: @Chris why do we need `by = col1` in first statement?

Comment: @user3664020 otherwise the table call will run on all elements in col3. You will find the most frequent instance of the entire table vs just the row.

Comment: @user3664020 If you want to skip the `by` (which should speed it up more), you could do `DT[, test := mapply(Mode, strsplit(col3, " "))]` or `DT[, test := sapply(strsplit(col3, " "), Mode)]` with Mode from David's answer.

Comment: @Chris i can do `by = col3` also then? Right?

Comment: @user3664020 yes you can, although depending on how many repeating column3's you have it may slow down your code, due to the O(n log n) point made above

Answer (score 1):

*(Edited as per comments below)*

Load the library

```
require(data.table)
```

Define the data

```
x <-
  data.table(
    col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    col2 = c(53, 45, 54, 97, 23),
    col3 = c(
      "aa aa aa aa ab ad af ae ar", "bb bb bb bb bt by bu bi bo", 
      "cc cc cc cc cd cy ch cn cd", "dd dd dd dd dt dy dj dk da",
      "ee ee ee ee et eh es er eg"),
    col4 = c(
      "aa bb ff ff","aa ff vv rr","dd dd rr gg",
      "yy yy rr rr","uu uu uu ee")
         )
```

Find the most freqent element in col3

```
x[,most_freq_word_in_col3:=sapply(col3,function(e){
  names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(e," "))),decreasing=TRUE)[1])})]
```

Check whether this element in col4

```
x[,out_col:=apply(cbind(most_freq_word_in_col3,col4),1,function(e){
  as.numeric(e[1] %in% unlist(strsplit(e[2]," ")))})]
```

Output:

```
> x
   col1 col2                       col3        col4 most_freq_word_in_col3 out_col
1:    1   53 aa aa aa aa ab ad af ae ar aa bb ff ff                     aa       1
2:    2   45 bb bb bb bb bt by bu bi bo aa ff vv rr                     bb       0
3:    3   54 cc cc cc cc cd cy ch cn cd dd dd rr gg                     cc       0
4:    4   97 dd dd dd dd dt dy dj dk da yy yy rr rr                     dd       0
5:    5   23 ee ee ee ee et eh es er eg uu uu uu ee                     ee       1
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg The second part is different, `%in%` instead of a regex.

Comment: @Frank I don't think that running an `apply` with margin of one is either necessary or any improvement

Comment: I got the idea for finding the most frequent element [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374651/finding-the-most-common-elements-in-a-vector-in-r), which is indeed similar to Chris'. The discussions between @Frank and Chris to speed up the code are interesting and inspiring. I will give it a go.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah, it should be `DT[, out_col := mapply("%in%", most_freq_word_in_col3, strsplit(col4, " "))]` or similar, which isn't so bad. Anyway, I'm just saying it's not an exact copy of another answer (which would be worse than being a suboptimal answer).