# Finding the most frequent value of a vector in r

Tags: r

I have a vector `x <- c(0.0,0.0,56.4,5.4)`. How can I return the most frequent value in this vector for this case it should be `0.0`?

I have tried the solution provided at [Finding the most common elements in a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374651/finding-the-most-common-elements-in-a-vector-in-r) but this returns a table, this is not what I expect exactly.

`x[which.max(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))]` works for this case but it doesn't work when I have a vector say `x <- c(278.0,0.0,27.8,27.8)` or `x <- c(NA,0.0,27.8,27.8)`.

I expect the following results.

> `x <- c(278.0,0.0,27.8,27.8)`
>
> `[1] I expect 27.8, not 278`
>
> `x <- c(NA,0.0,27.8,27.8)`
>
> `[1] I expect 27.8, not NA`

Comment: When you have floating point, it is also a good practise to round it as numbers can get different

Comment: @akrun this answers my question exactly. Thanks