# How to convert dates to counts of dates?

Tags: r, date

I have `POSIXct` dates stored in a vector, and I want to plot/extract the number of occurrences for each date.

```
head(dates1, 10)
 [1] NA               NA               NA               "2012-01-19 UTC"
 [5] NA               NA               NA               "2013-04-02 UTC"
 [9] "2012-10-04 UTC" "2012-12-20 UTC"
```

The closest I get is this:

```
hist(dates1, breaks = 27, freq = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 80))
```

[image: histogram]

However, this is quite crude. What I would like to do is to convert the data to a vector with counts of each date so that I can do more computations and plots on it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A developmental comment is more helpful than a downvote...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting the Number of Elements With The Values of x in a Vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector)

Comment: Those look like class `Date` values to me, not `POSIXct` date-times.  Perhaps something like `x <- sample(Sys.Date()+0:9, 50, TRUE); plot(table(x))` would be more what you are looking for

Comment: A `dput(head(dates1))` would make it easier to provide assistance.

Answer (score 1):

As [Richard Scriven notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661982/how-to-convert-dates-to-counts-of-dates#comment43739905_27661982), these look like `Date`s. No matter whether they are `Date`s or `POSIXct`s, this will likely be helpful:

```
foo <- table(as.Date(dates1))
```

This will of course only give you *nonzero* counts, which may not be what you want. If you want (possibly) zero counts for dates that do not appear in `dates1`, then convert it to a `factor` before `table`ing:

```
dates1 <- as.Date(dates1)
foo <- factor(dates1,levels=as.character(seq(min(dates1),max(dates1),by="day")))
table(foo)
```