# R: show ALL rows with duplicated elements in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

Does a function like this exist in any package?

```
isdup <- function (x) duplicated (x) | duplicated (x, fromLast = TRUE)
```

My intention is to use it with `dplyr` to display **all** rows with duplicated values in a given column. I need the first occurrence of the duplicated element to be shown as well.

In this data.frame for instance

```
dat <- as.data.frame (list (l = c ("A", "A", "B", "C"), n = 1:4))
dat

> dat
  l n
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 B 3
4 C 4
```

I would like to display the rows where column `l` is duplicated ie. those with an **A** value doing:

```
library (dplyr)
dat %>% filter (isdup (l))
```

returns

```
  l n
1 A 1
2 A 2
```

Comment: Why not just use the one you defined?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148567/fastest-way-to-remove-all-duplicates-in-r/37149066#37149066) for alternative methods along with an efficiency analysis.

Comment: Is just easier If I do not need to write it every time... thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 23):

`dat %>% group_by(l) %>% filter(n() > 1)`

I don't know if it exists in any package, but since you can implement it easily, I'd say just go ahead and implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is clean and works for me. The answers given in the supposed duplicate question links only appeared to deal with duplicates within a single vector, not returning all columns of a data frame where a single column has duplicates.

Comment: This works perfectly.