# R: Removing duplicate elements in a vector

Tags: r, vector, filter

I have a vector like this:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7)

> x
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7
```

I want to get rid of duplicates and get something like this:

```
> [1] 1 2 3 7
```

**My attempt**

```
y = x[duplicated(x)]

> y
[1] 4 5 6

> x[x!=y]
[1] 1 2 3 7
Warning message:
In x != y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is this error something I should worry about?

Is there another way to do this without getting an error?

Comment: Since `y` is a vector here, you need to use `%in%` operator. `x[!(x %in% y)]`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is fine, but contains a malapropism. In programming, a 'double' element usually refers to a number stored as a double precision floating-point, rather than a 'duplicate'. You''ll note that your original tag `double` refers to this sense of the word double, not the one you meant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @Psidom: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Hugh: Ah yes, i wasn't sure how to word my problem. Thank you for the useful tip - will keep that in mind!

Comment: Can I ask the context of this question? Partly I suspect an X-Y problem here.

Comment: @Hugh: I wanted to get rid of rows in my data frame with duplicate dates

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate but I can't find it right now, but `x[ave(x,x,FUN=length)==1]`

Comment: @thelatemail, maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7854433/4408538)

Comment: @thelatemail, I found a couple more: [post1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13763216/4408538), [post2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37148567/4408538).

Answer (score 5):

Beware using consecutive numbers in your tests!

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7)
x1 <- c(-1, -1, 2, 8, 8, 15)

keep_singles <- function(v){
  v[!(v %in% v[duplicated(v)])] 
}

keep_singles(x)

[1] 1 2 3 7

keep_singles(x1)

[1]  2 15
```

Comment: Ahhh was just going to post this answer in addition to mine, but you beat me to it! Definitely the cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do it using base R that doesn't give you a warning message.

*Edit:* More flexible answer from @Hugh's suggestion

```
y = as.numeric(names(which(table(x)==1)))

y
[1] 1 2 3 7
```

Comment: Not quite correct. Using your method on `x <- c(-1, -1, 2, 8, 8, 15)` returns `2 4`. I think you want `x[which(table(x) == 1)]` (*i.e.* the values not the indices).

Comment: Unfortunately trying that on the original problem I get: `1 2 3 4`

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion was wrong, to get the values it would be `as.numeric(names(table(x))[table(x) == 1])`. Unless OP wants the indices, I think your answer is currently incorrect.

Comment: No worries, I should've stress tested my answer a little more - thanks for pointing that out! I think this works as well `y = as.numeric(names((which(table(x)==1))))`.

Comment: That's what comments are for! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `duplicated` alone

```
x[!(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE))]
#[1] 1 2 3 7
```

Comment: Nice answer. I use a very similar function for stuff like this... `x[duplicated(x) + duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)==0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way as your code, but use `[!x%in%y]` rather than `[x!=y]`

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7)

y <- x[duplicated(x)]

z <- x[!x%in%y]

print(z)
[1] 1 2 3 7
```