# Counting the number of elements in vector x which equal any vector element in vector y

Tags: r

I need to count the number of elements in vector `x` which equal any vector element in vector `y`.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector) I can count the number of elements in vector `x` which equal to value in scalar `y with code:

```
x <- c(4,23,4,23,5,43,54,56,657,67,67,435,
             453,435,324,34,456,56,567,65,34,435, 675)

sum(x == 67)
```

**Question:**  How to count the number of elements in vector `x` which equal any vector element in vector `y`?

Comment: @Rushabh Patel why you deleted updated answer? It was working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try length-which-in:

```
length(which(x %in% y))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

For All matches use this:

```
length(na.omit(match(x,y)))
```

For unique Matches use this:

```
length(intersect(x,y))
```

Comment: This code gives the sum of "if element from `y` was matched at least one time in x" and here "several occurrences of `y` in `x` is counted as `1`".

Comment: @SmokeyShakers I changed my answer.