# dplyr or tidy way of counting the number of each unique value in a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

There are [numerous ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector) of counting the values in a vector, including the familiar (but [fraught](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923574/5783745)) `table()`

Is there a safe/reliable method that uses `dplyr` / tidyverse?

Note [`plyr::count()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16965258/5783745) seems to work nicely, but is obviously from plyr rather than dplyr

```
c(1,3,3,3,4,4) %>% plyr::count()
  x freq
1 1    1
2 3    3
3 4    2
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` functions are better suited for dataframe/tibbles than vectors. You can use `dplyr::count` after converting vector to tibble.

```
c(1,3,3,3,4,4) %>% tibble::as_tibble() %>% count(value)

#  value     n
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     3     3
#3     4     2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also convert to `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
c(1,3,3,3,4,4) %>%
     data.frame(value = .) %>%
     count(value)
```

---

Or just use `table`

```
c(1,3,3,3,4,4) %>%
    table %>%
    as.data.frame
```