# find same group in R

Tags: r

I have data table like this

```
year       value
2010        25          
2011       168          
2012        48          
2010       189          
2011       192          
2012       38           
2010       175          
2011       55           
2012       48
```

I want to distinguish my data to be like this

```
year       value

2010        3 (25 189 175: = 33.33% )
2011        3 (168 192 55 : = 33.33%)
2012        3 (48 38 48: = 33.33%)
```

for further plotting bar graph which have 3 main groups (2010 2011 2012) in X-axis and % of members in each year in Y-axis

What should I do? I'm a beginner in R program. Thank you in advanced :D

Comment: `table(x$year)`, where `x` is your data frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of elements with the values of x in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector)

Comment: `library(dplyr)`  `count(dat, year)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this

```
> data.frame(xtabs(~year, df))
  year Freq
1 2010    3
2 2011    3
3 2012    3
```

or the plot

```
barplot(prop.table(xtabs(~year, df)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should note that for plotting the graph, the transformation you describe is not necessary. But you can do

```
dplyr::count(your_data, year)
```

returning

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   year     n
  <dbl> <int>
1  2010     3
2  2011     3
3  2012     3
```