# Is there an R function to find count of maximum number in a data

Tags: r

I want to find how many maximum values in a data. I have used length but it gives me 1. The maximum value is 9 and I have two 9s, I want is to display 2. Is there a function in R that I can use?

```
data <- c(1, 3, 8, 9, 0, 9)
max(data)
length(max(data))
```

Comment: You could do `sum(data == max(data))`.

Comment: or `sort(table(data),decreasing=TRUE)[1]`

Comment: Related: [Counting the number of elements with the values of x in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector), where you apparently know how to calculate 'x'.

Answer (score -1):

```
data <- c(1, 3, 8, 9, 0, 9)
length(which(data==max(data)))
```